# Datadriven shell programming? Suggestions, please

Tags: shell, data-driven

I'd like to convert my shell script to use a datadriven approach. But since there are no "tables" type values in any shell (that I know of), what are suggested alternative ways to do this?

What I'm looking for is solutions that would allow one to do things like:

```
animals = [['horse', 300 'brown'],
           ['cat', 3, 'black'],
           ['elephant', 3000, 'grey'],
           ['mouse', 0.3, 'grey']]
for a in animals ; do
  echo "A typical $a[1] is $a[3] and weighs about $a[2] kilograms."
done
```

More precisely, I'd like to try a number of commands and see if one of them is available, and then send arguments to it:

```
commands = [['c1', '-m', '-i'],
            ['c2', '-message', '-icon'],
            ['c3', '/m', '/i']]
for c in commands ; do
  if exists c[1] ; then
    command = c[1]
    message_option = c[2]
    icon_option = c[3]
    break;
  fi
done
$command $message_option "message" $icon_option icon
```

Comment: Why not put your 'table' data into a file and then read from it using `awk` or similar programs?

Comment: Which shell are you using? `bash`, `ksh` or `zsh`?

Comment: I was considering `python` but decided against it for portability issues. So my approach was `bash`. The script needs to do a lot of other things, but it would be interesting to explore a combination with `awk` since that is also available "everywhere". So how would a shell script call `awk` to do the example (which I'll update to pinpoint more precisely what I need to do)?

Comment: You don't need `awk`, can do with a simple `bash` built in arrays for this.

Comment: `awk '{print "A typical",$1,"is", $3, "and weighs about" ,$2 "kilos."}' inputfile`

Comment: @thoni56: Refer my answer below and let me know if you were looking for a similar logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No bashisms needed. This can be neatly solved with a **here-document** read by a `while read` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read animal weigth colour; do
  printf '%s\n' "A typical $animal is $colour and weighs about $weight kilos."
done << EOF
horse 300 brown
cat 3 black
elephant 3000 grey
mouse 0.3 grey
EOF
```

Observe how this refers to the elements by name, not cryptic indexing with 1, 2, 3. It doesn't fork/exec any external commands and beats the 3 awks in the loop body seen in another answer hands down.

Comment: @Inian and Jens having the same profil picture is pretty confusing lol

Comment: @Mayerz And we're not the only ones :-)

Comment: @Jens: Provided an approach using arrays only because the OP's post looked similar to that.

Answer (score 2):

You can define and use [associative-arrays](http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/) in `bash` for your requirement.

```
#!/bin/bash

# declaring the Associative array
declare -a animals

animals[0]="'horse':300:'brown'"
animals[1]="'cat':3:'black'"
animals[2]="'elephant':3000:'grey'"
animals[3]="'mouse':0.3:'grey'"

for animal in "${animals[@]}"
do
    myArray=(${animal//:/ })
    printf "A typical "${myArray[0]}" is "${myArray[2]}" and weighs about "${myArray[1]}" kilograms.\n"
done
```

The only tricky part in the above is [parameter-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of type

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
          The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. 
If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced.
```

So ideally the string `'horse':300:'brown'` is split as individual elements and stored in the array `myArray` which is later used to access individual elements in a C-style loop.

Comment: @thoni56: And I thought you need an approach using arrays from your example! But now being un-accepted? :(

Comment: I wasn't specifically asking for how to implement arrays, but data-driven shell scripting. I accepted your answer because it was definitely the best at the time, and I'm still up-voting you answer for teaching me about bash arrays, but the answer from @Jens was an even better solution to my actual problem. Consider the acceptance of his answer a signal that his understanding of what I wanted to achieve was even better than yours.

Comment: @thoni56: fair enough! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
cat file
'horse', 300, 'brown'
'cat', 3, 'black'
'elephant', 3000, 'grey'
'mouse', 0.3, 'grey'

for i in {1..4} ; 
do 
    animal=$(awk -F, -v var="$i" 'NR== var {print $1}' file) 
    weight=$(awk -F, -v var="$i" 'NR== var {print $2}' file) 
    colour=$(awk -F, -v var="$i" 'NR== var {print $3}' file) 
    echo "A typical "$animal" is "$colour" and weighs about "$weight" kilos." 
done
```

Output-

```
A typical 'horse' is 'brown' and weighs about  300 kilos.
A typical 'cat' is  'black' and weighs about  3 kilos.
A typical 'elephant' is  'grey' and weighs about  3000 kilos.
A typical 'mouse' is  'grey' and weighs about  0.3 kilos.
```

Comment: This is a waste of CPU cycles. It forks 12 processes and reads the same file 12 times.

Comment: Performance was not one of the requirements, but that might be valid observation in some circumstances.